# Can't find the file directory after I stopped recording with MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediarecorder

I'm making an app that records sound as long as the imagebutton is touched and held, but I have a problem getting to the file after I'm done recording.

This is the code for output file:

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        externalStoragePath = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(externalStoragePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }
    else
    {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }
```

I logged it and this is the result:

```
07-31 01:49:54.582: I/storage(332): File saved to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/cache/easyvoiceno‌​tepad/test.3gp
```

I can't find this directory anywhere on my device (I'm not even using emulator), my device is Samsung Galaxy Nexus by the way if that helps.

Also, here is the full mainactivity code, if maybe the problem is somewhere else:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaRecorder recorder;
String storagePath;
String externalStoragePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //AUDIO RECORDER
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.reset();       
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        externalStoragePath = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(externalStoragePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }
    else
    {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }

    //IMAGE BUTTON ONTOUCHLISTENER
    final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
    recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                    recorder = null;
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(STORAGE_SERVICE, "File saved to: " + externalStoragePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
} //END OF ONCREATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Context.getExternalCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29) is meant for temporary files.

According to the API:

`External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it.`

This is also true of files stored at [Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

So you likely want [Context.getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) or [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29). The latter will allow your files to persist if your app is uninstalled, the former will not.